# Split/Cut polygons within feature classes based on a polygon mask

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3

I am looking for a way to split features based on a mask. The end goal is the deleting of the features within the mask, without creating an output.

The polygons are bigger than my intented mask, but I just need to delete the area within the mask. Therefor I cannot delete based on location or attribute. By splitting these polyongs based on the mask, I can then select them and delete them. Afterwards I want to "paste" new data in the deleted area.

I am looking for a way to do this within modelbuilder or Arcpy, though my knowledge of Arcpy is beginner at best.

I am using ArcGis 10.3.1.

Clarification of the question:[image]

Comment: Cant you: 1- select by location, 2 - Erase with output written to in_memory, 3 - Delete Selection, 4 - Append output from erase

Comment: [Erase](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/erase.htm) is the key to your task.